# SQl2005 SSIS DTS_E_PRODUCTLEVELTOLOW

Tags: ssis

Hi
I am trying to build an SSIS package to import text files to SQL data tables and then move the text files to a 'processed' file.

I can get the package to run successfully on my workstation in Visual Studio 2005 (although I got 'access denied' on the 'move' operation but I will worry about that later).

However, when I deploy to the SQL server, and execute the package on the server, I get DTS_E_PRODUCTLEVELTOLOW error on the import to SQL stage. I have checked the SSIS service is running on the server which it is.

The data upload is very simple - just the first column from the text file plus the file name in two columns, so none of the 'smart' stuff that might not be installed.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: As a side note: Anyone laugh at the grammar of the warning?

Comment: Lol, yes I noticed that too.  Or to.  :)

Comment: Yeah, someone already mentioned that in the Community Content box on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337371.aspx  :)

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337371.aspx

says

> **Possible Causes**
>
> This message might appear because of one of the following problems:
>
> - You have installed BI Development Studio but you have not installed Integration Services. Running packages outside Business Intelligence Development Studio requires the installation of Integration Services.
> - Your package may be attempting to use advanced components for Analysis Services, data mining, or text mining that are available only in SQL Server Enterprise.

In the unlikely case you are using SQL Server 2005 without any service packs, there was a problem with running the Import-/Export Data Wizard. This problem was solved beginning with SP1.

A great collection of tips are in this blog post:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michen/archive/2006/11/11/ssis-product-level-is-insufficient.aspx

**Update:**

To find out, what SQL Server Version you are running, execute the following query on your server:

```
 SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('productversion'), SERVERPROPERTY ('productlevel'), SERVERPROPERTY ('edition')
```

The second column of the result tells you the service pack level.

Comment: I am pretty sure Integration Services is running : services on the server shows

Comment: I am pretty sure Integration Services is running : services on server shows

Comment: Sorry, not sure what happened above. Services on server shows SQL Server Integration Services as 'Started' - is that it? Also, not using any advanced components.

Comment: Did you check the version / service pack level? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321185

Comment: SP1 or later (hint: have a look at my links *g*)

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 9.00.4035.00 Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools 2005.090.4035.00 Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC) 6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255) Microsoft MSXML 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 Microsoft Internet Explorer 8.0.7600.16385 Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0.50727.4952 Operating System 6.1.7600 - is this correct?

Comment: 9.00.4035.00 SP3 Standard Edition

Comment: Well it's not a Service Pack level problem then. Are you sure you really execute your package on the server? This is only the case if your package is called by a SQL Agent Job on the server or if you run Management Studio on the server remotely (via Terminal Services) or you are sitting right at the server (unlikely).

Comment: Yes, I connected to Integration Services in SQL Management Studio, and tried to 'Run Package'

Comment: Please reread my last comment carefully: Are you running SQL Management Studio ON THE SERVER?